# What's the probability formula for succeeding at a Complex Skill Check?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, statistics

[The SRD page for Complex Skill Checks](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/buildingCharacters/complexSkillChecks.htm) gives percentage numbers for a number of different scenarios. For example, if the required roll on a 1d20 is 2, the chance of success on a simple check is 95% (which is obvious), but succeeding on a before-3-failures 3-successes-required complex check is 99.88%, for 5-sucesses-required it's 99.62%, and for 10-successes-required it's 98.04%.

What formula did they use to get those numbers?

Comment: This is probably better asked on Math.se or Stats.se, as there is nothing here that requires RPG expertise and a lot that requires maths/stats expertise.

Comment: I would, except that they'd refer me to here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915353/the-probability-of-having-k-successes-before-r-failures-in-a-sequence-of-ind and that doesn't actually answer this question. They'd likely tell me that the table was simply wrong.

Comment: That still doesn't mean it involves our site's expertise. If the table is simply wrong, then we *certainly* won't be able to tell you what formula was used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not something that RPG expertise can help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the **SUM** of the Negative Binomial Distributions, running from 0 failures to "the # of allowed failures" - 1.

For example:

```
  | A                         | B
--+---------------------------+--
1 | # of Required Successes   | 3
2 | Trial Success Probability | 95%
3 | Before 1 Failure          | =NEGBINOMDIST(0,B1,B2)
4 | Before 2 Failures         | =B3+NEGBINOMDIST(1,B1,B2)
5 | Before 3 Failures         | =B4+NEGBINOMDIST(2,B1,B2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the authors used the [negative binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) which is used in cases like this to calculate the probability of a certain # of successes in a sequence of Bernoulli trials before a given # of failures occurs.

Comment: Actually the NegBinomDist is used to calculate the probability of drawing a certain number of failures before a certain number of SUCCESSES (given a probability of success in independent trials). It's basically the opposite (although not quite, as if it were actually the opposite we could just go 1-NegBinomDist to get the answer here).

Comment: For example, 1-NEGBINOMDIST(3,3,95%) = 99.8928% (which is different from the table on the SRD page). Likewise, 1-NEGBINOMDIST(3,5,95%) = 99.9994% (which, again, is different from the table on the SRD page).

Comment: @EmrysTernal - Using the Excel NEGBINOM.DIST function, try Prob(3 successes|< 3 failures, p=.95) = 1 - (NEGBINOM.DIST(0,3,.95) + NEGBINOM.DIST(1,3,.95) + NEGBINOM.DIST(2,3,.95))

Comment: RobertF, could you fold anything important in the comments into your answer?